# Plotly Dash NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to dash and I was running the below code which is taken from plotly dash website.But when I am running the code I am getting an error as "NameError: name 'app' is not defined".May I know where I went wrong

**Code**

```
import datetime

import dash
import dash_html_components as html

def serve_layout():
    return html.H1('The time is: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

app.layout = serve_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

**Error**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-440bd7faf6a6> in <module>
      7     return html.H1('The time is: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
      8 
----> 9 app.layout = serve_layout
     10 
     11 if __name__ == '__main__':

NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Comment: That's only a part of the code. Start the tutorial from the beginning, not from the middle.

Comment: correct now it is working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you resolved your own question by going through the tutorial in more depth, but I am adding an answer anyway so that anyone who encounters the same problem can find the answer here.

You need the following line to define the dash app:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
```